# How to avoid Confliction due to "Same signal, different slots" in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals

I am working on an application which has 3 plug-ins. The main application is a Qt project and along with it we also add 3 more Qt projects which are the plug-ins to the main application.

I am calling a connect statement in one project where the SIGNAL is **`triggered()`**, the object is shown below and has a slot **slt_menuSetIngestDir()**. I am calling a connect statement in another project which has the same object, same SIGNAL **`triggered()`** but has a different slot **slt_IngestDir().**

**Here is the sample connect statement in Project 1:**

```
connect(PluginLocalManager::getInstance()->getEventIF()->getMenuAction(M_TOOL_SETINGESTDIR), SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(slt_menuSetIngestDir()) );
```

**Sample Connect statement in Project 2:**

```
connect(PluginLocalManager::getInstance()->getEventIF()->getMenuAction(M_TOOL_SETINGESTDIR), SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(slt_IngestDir()) );
```

The problem is when I run the application, and when the click the particular option, it triggers the SIGNAL using the same object and calls two different slots at the sametime.

Is it possible that I can disconnect a signal in Project 2 and make sure my connect statement in Project 1 works specifically for Project 1 and vice versa??? I have come across `disconnect` statement in Qt but It looks like I am missing something. Please help!!

Comment: Project 1 and project 2 create different binaries, right?

Comment: @hate-engine: No the .exe is created in the main project. Like I mentioned these connect statements are present in Plugin 1 and Plugin 2 project respectively.

Comment: how come the the object instance appeared in two plugins..

Comment: @zzk: Object instance is part of a class which is present in the main application. I am just using it in two different plug-ins.

Comment: is it true that if project 1 exists, then the SLOT in project 2 is useless? or you still want to SLOT there? which SLOT you'd like it to receive the signal emitted by the common sender? And if you don't want a SLOT to receive signal, why connect them in the first place?

Comment: @zzk: If project 1 exists and signal is emitted then slot in the same project shud be called and the slot in project 2 should be useless. In simple terms, slot in project 2 should not get triggered and vice versa

Comment: i'm confused. this object who sends signal exists in both project 1 and 2. So if it emits signal, according to your statement, both SLOTs should do something. I don't know how to understand your statement, seems to contradictory to me.

Comment: @zzk: Basically main-menu for the entire application which consists of 3 plugins is COMMON. Since the menu items in all the plugins are same, I want to trigger different slot in the same plugin based on the plugin I am operating and not interfere the slots present in other plugins which have the same object. Am I clear???

Comment: @zzk: well object who sends signal is present in main application. I use this in my plugins i.e. proj1 and proj 2. Here I have to use the same object in the connect statement but it shud trigger the slot for the respective plugin. If I am clicking menu item of proj 1, it shud trigger slot of proj 1 only and not trigger slot of proj 2.

Comment: The important question is: How would your application know which plugin _should_ be called?  If you know that then your design should follow from it.  Direct signal/slot connections might not be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disconnect all slots from chosen signal, try to use
`connect(PluginLocalManager::getInstance()->getEventIF()->getMenuAction(M_TOOL_SETINGESTDIR), SIGNAL(triggered()), 0, 0)`

But it looks like bad design, I think you should manage connections in your main app.